# Recursive Queries (CTE) to find an archive permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Archives](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ParentArchiveId] [int] NULL


CREATE TABLE [ArchivePermissions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ArchiveId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [PermissionId] [int] NULL
```

and I need to find permission for an archive.

If the archive doesn't have permissions for the user I have to go up, to the parent archives till the top archive.

I'm trying to do it with CTE:

```
            ;WITH RESULT (ParentArchiveId,ArchiveId, PermissionId, UserId, Level)
        AS
        (
             --anchor
             SELECT E.ParentArchiveId,E.[Id], A.PermissionId, UserId ,0 AS Level
             FROM Archives AS E  
             LEFT JOIN ArchivePermissions AS A ON e.Id = A.ArchiveId
             WHERE E.Id = @ArchiveId
             AND A.UserId = @UserId
             UNION ALL
             --outer
             SELECT e.ParentArchiveId ,e.[Id], D.PermissionId, UserId, Level+1 --switched parent/child
             FROM Archives AS E 
             INNER JOIN RESULT AS D  
             ON E.Id  = D.ParentArchiveId 
        )

        SELECT TOP 1 @PermissionId = PermissionId FROM RESULT as d
        WHERE d.PermissionId is not NULL
        order by Level asc
```

But it doesn't work. I can't understand where is the problem...

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: It just doesn't return the values. I suppose that you are right I need to get the hierarchy first and then look at permissions. I'll check it later today. Thank you, Gordon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the "anchor" part of the recursive CTE returns no rows.  You want to get the hierarchy first and then look at permissions:

```
with ancestors as (
      select id, id as parentarchiveid, 0 as level
      from archives a
      where id = @ArchiveId
      union all
      select anc.id, a.parentarchiveid, level + 1
      from ancestors anc join
           archives a
           on anc.id = a.parentarchiveid
    )
select TOP 1 @PermissionId = PermissionId
from ancestors a join
     archivepermissions ap
     on a.parentarchiveid = ap.archiveid and
        ap.userid = @UserId
order by level asc;
```

Comment: Gordon, in the case a user has permission only on the top archive I do not get the results.

Comment: I just modified it to use the `parentarchiveid` for the `join` (and for level 0 to start with the same id rather than the parent).  That should fix this problem.

Comment: Gordon, it didn't fix it. Could you, please, review it one more time? I do not how to get it work :( But I need it :)

Comment: @IgorOlikh . . . Could you create a SQL Fiddle with appropriate data?

Comment: When users want to get permissions for the archive with id=3 I need to return them the permissions of the top archive with id=1 because only it has permissions for this user.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
            ;WITH Ancestors
        AS
        (
             SELECT E.[Id], E.ParentArchiveId, 0 as Level -- , A.PermissionId, UserId ,0 AS Level
             FROM Archives AS E  
             WHERE E.Id = @DocItemArchiveId
             UNION ALL
             SELECT a.Id , a.[ParentArchiveId], Level + 1  --, D.PermissionId, UserId, Level+1 --switched parent/child
             FROM Archives AS a 
             JOIN Ancestors AS anc  
             ON anc.ParentArchiveId  = a.Id 
             WHERE LEVEL < 10
        )

        SELECT TOP 1 @PermissionId = PermissionId FROM Ancestors as anc
        LEFT JOIN ArchivePermissions as ap ON anc.Id = ap.ArchiveId
        AND ap.UserId = @UserId
        WHERE ap.PermissionId is not NULL
        order by Level asc
```